# Footer always on bottom, 3 columns

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to figure out how to create a layout with:
- a fixed height header and not fixed
- two sidebars (one in each side)
- a column between the sidebars
- a fixed height footer sticky at the bottom of the page and that moves accordingly to the content (**here is the problem**, *maybe*)

I've seen many similar questions, but none of them seen to work with 3 columns.
I'm not sure, but I think it's something related to floating the columns of the content.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">Header is ok</div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="column-left"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="column-right"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

Here's the CSS code:

```
html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
height: 100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
background: green;
height: 60px;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
}
#container {
margin: 0 auto;
width: 80%;
padding-top: 60px; /* size of header */
padding-bottom: 100px; /* size of footer */
background: red;
height: 100%;
}
#footer {
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
}
#column-left {
width: 20%;
min-height: 100%;
background: yellow;
float: left;
}
#column-right {
width: 20%;
min-height: 100%;
background: yellow;
float: left;
}
#content {
float: left;
width: 60%;
min-height: 100%;
background: pink;
}
```

Here's an example of what's happening when I add some content:
http://jsfiddle.net/Lzp67xyu/

Comment: fix the `column-right` div

Comment: @Sidsec9 Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a margin-bottom on the container with your columns in it will keep the space below it where the footer would be.

```
.columnncontainer{
    width:80%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    background-color:yellow;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle I came up with as example:
http://jsfiddle.net/y5xwop8h/1/

Comment: It looks very nice. How do I stretch the height to fill the rest of the page ?

Comment: I changed the link to the fiddle, I hope this helps :)

Comment: I've changed the footer position to `absolute` and added a `margin-bottom: -100px` _(sum of header and footer)_. Now it looks just like I wanted. Thanks again! ;) See: http://jsfiddle.net/y5xwop8h/4/

Comment: One last question regarding this: why is it generating a scroll bar? since there's not enought content.. See: http://jsfiddle.net/y5xwop8h/5/

Comment: One of the containers, I suspect the body or container div, is just a bit bigger than the page. Probably due to a margin or padding somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/Lzp67xyu/1/)

Change positioning of `#footer` to `relative` and add `clear:both` to `#footer`.

That is, the CSS for `#footer` would be like

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)

> The clear property specifies on which sides of an element where
>   floating elements are not allowed to float.

Comment: I might have misread when he said "sticky" I thought he meant it scrolled with the page?

Comment: @Lal actually i wanted it to scroll with the page :) Btw, your solution also worked! Thank you very much ;)